# Custom Inheritance in Delphi , Can we do it in an elegant way?

Tags: delphi

Look at this Code:

```
    TSuper = class   // An Ancestor Class.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod; // The Ancestor Common Method for All.
    procedure GroupSpecificMethod; // The Ancestor Specific Method.
  end;

  TSubOne = class(TSuper)  // A Subclass needs to implement GroupSpecificMethod.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod; 
    procedure GroupSpecificMethod; 
  end;

  TSubTwo = class(TSuper) // Another Subclass needs to implement GroupSpecificMethod.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod; 
    procedure GroupSpecificMethod; 
  end;

  TSubThree = class(TSuper) // This class Must not have GroupSpecificMethod.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod; 
  end;
```

We have a SuperClass that gives origin to a group of subclasses.

How we can enforce to inherit a GroupSpecificMethod from the Ancestor Class to only some of the Subclasses and not to all of them.

I need it in an elegant way not to introduce an **Empty** Method within the Subclass.

Does OOP in Delphi support this? How?

Comment: How do "some of the subclasses" identify as "must not inherit"? How should a parent class know who should have permission and who doesn't? If you mean "should not" instead of "must not" then the child class can at any time ignore (override) the parent's class methods.

Comment: Yes, as a hack , we can override the method of the child class by an empty method ( Do nothing Method ) , But do we have an elegant OOP way for that? I'm asking.

Comment: As a comment, If we can not do that, ie, specifically inherit Methods over the Siblings according to our needs, is I'm right when asking for a New feature for the OOP to do that?

Comment: Use interfaces, and let the child classes decide which interfaces they implement

Comment: suppose we can write like this ( I'm supposing that this feature is present):                               TSubThree = class(TSuper) // This class Must not have GroupSpecificMethod.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod;
     procedure GroupSpecificMethod;  Cancel; // this is where TSubThree stops using the method 
  end;

Comment: You don't need a new feature. Just use an empty overridden method, if that's really what you need. However, most of the time, you won't need it.

Comment: Yes, I'm using interfaces in my application, But I MUST use a single Interface only because I use the Factory Method Pattern by this Interface, this to get the benifit of Reference counting. so can not use more than one interface.

Comment: You use static methods and not virtual methods. Is that intentional? In terms of programming style, it reminds me of JavaScript.

Comment: @HasDev a class implementing multiple interfaces doesn't affect its ability to use reference counting or factory creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in Delphi (and probably in any OO language) to automatically empty the implementation of a method below a certain class in the hierarchy. There are two reasons for that:

1. You can always do it yourself by overriding the method with an empty
   implementation.
2. Such a need is very rare and may be the sign of a bad hierarchy design.

Answer (score 1):

Your desire violates OOP principles. It looks like your application has architecture issues..

Answer (score 0):

This is where [Visibility of class members](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Visibility_of_Class_Members) comes in handy.

If you want your `GroupSpecificMethod` to be visible only in some of its subclasses declare it as `private` or `strict private` in your `TSuper` class.

```
  TSuper = class   // An Ancestor Class.
  strict private
    procedure GroupSpecificMethod; // The Ancestor Specific Method declared as strict private.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod; // The Ancestor Common Method for All.
  end;

  TSubOne = class(TSuper)  // A Subclass needs to implement GroupSpecificMethod.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod;
    procedure GroupSpecificMethod; // The Ancestor Specific Method visibility changed to public
  end;

  TSubTwo = class(TSuper) // Another Subclass needs to implement GroupSpecificMethod.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod;
    procedure GroupSpecificMethod; // The Ancestor Specific Method visibility changed to public
  end;

  TSubThree = class(TSuper) // This class Must not have GroupSpecificMethod.
  public
    procedure CommonMethod;
  end;
```

NOTE:

- This prevents `GroupSpecificMethod` to be used directly from `TSuper`. So you will always need to subclass `TSuper` in order to use `GroupSpecificMethod`
- Also this does not prevent any subclass of TSubThree to make `GroupSpecificMethod` public.

Comment: If I understand your comments correctly, you're wrong in saying that "GroupSpecificMethod" is prevented from being used in TSuper. Actually, you are preventing it from being used in ANY subclasses. The visibility modifier you're looking for is PROTECTED. And if you want it to not be able to be called from TSuper and be forced to override it in subclasses, you need to declare it VIRTUAL; ABSTRACT; In subclasses you then need to declare it OVERRIDE; When you then call GroupSpecificMethod inside TSuper, it will call the subclass method - or abort with an AbstractError exception if not overridden.